# Locking only entrance/exit of a Queue in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have a system which contains -

```
Queue & 2 types of instances -
                             1.push to the Queue
                             2.pull from Queue
```

I want to push and pull from the Queue in the same time but i don't sure (I didn't find in documentation and didn't find the implementation) 
if the queue protects from collisions of access to the same memory

```
for example:
    There is zero elements in the Queue -> I push and then I pull in the same time
```

My question is if the Queue not protects it, there is any way to lock only the entrance or the exit of the Queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Queue class knows about concurrent access and handles it correctly. If you pull from the queue (`queue.get()`) and there is nothing in the queue then the call will block or time out. If you push to the queue (`queue.put()`) then this will be correctly handled and the call will only block or time out if you have set a maximum size for the queue and it is full.

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) says:

> The `queue` module implements multi-producer, multi-consumer queues. It
>   is especially useful in threaded programming when information must be
>   exchanged safely between multiple threads. The `Queue` class in this
>   module implements all the required locking semantics. It depends on
>   the availability of thread support in Python; see the `threading`
>   module.

Comment: Thanks,that's what i looked for!